# Inline webworker: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an `inline webworker` as follows:

```
var blob = new Blob([document.querySelector("worker").textContent]);
var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

However I am getting an error:

```
Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
```

What am I missing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9u45Q/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `querySelector` pattern does not match anything.
I think you should change it to:

```
document.querySelector("#worker") // <- Added # to match the id
```

Comment: Now it is throwing an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  `

Comment: @RahulDesai That's another story. You should post another question since it is another problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403904/inline-webworker-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier

Comment: @RahulDesai Then you should approve an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had removed the html code from my page by mistake.
Since it couldn't find the h1 tag, I got the same error.

So basically the problem is; it couldn't find the html control so it couldn't read the html property textContent.

so this is my html(I added back and worked fine then);

```
<h1>Welcome to app!!</h1>
```

and this is my Jasmine test code;

```
expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to app!!');
```