# Inline webworker: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an inline webworker as follows:

```
var blob = new Blob([document.querySelector("#worker").textContent]);
var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

However I am getting an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Also a note saying:

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "blob:http%3A//fiddle.jshell.net/7284b49c-b4a5-4523-8a06-bbf98cd7e03f".`

What am I missing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9u45Q/1/)

**UPDATE**:
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9u45Q/2/

The error occurs when you are filling the form and you reach to the `Number of Tickets` field

Comment: Is you fiddle working? I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your fiddle only does: `new Blob([document.querySelector("#worker")]);` add in `.textContent` and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/9u45Q/4/

Comment: @RobH Works very well now! However, I am still getting that note in the `console`. Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First error is caused by a simple typo in your fiddle, you had:

```
new Blob([document.querySelector("#worker")]);
```

But you needed:

```
new Blob([document.querySelector("#worker").textContent]);
```

The warning about your mime-type can be solved by setting the type on the blob when you create it:

```
new Blob([document.querySelector("#worker").textContent],
            {type: 'text/javascript'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9u45Q/6/

Edit: Fixed type.

Comment: Can you explain or point me to the documentation about the `.textcontent` and `type` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers specifically the "Embedded Workers" section.